# New to Ember.js, I can render all templates except my root application template

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I apologize in advanced if this is a simple mistake or I'm not aware of something very obvious. I've looked through other users problems on StackOverflow but still can't get mine to work. What am I doing wrong? I'm taking a tutorial online and my code looks identical to my instructors.

My problem is that I can get Ember to render my templates of "about", "about/team", "contact" through typing my routes into the URL in my browser, but as soon as I add a handlebars template to my application (which I plan on then using an unordered list to navigate to those routes/templates) it wont render my application template.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Let's Learn Ember.js</title>

    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>

<script>
  window.App = Ember.Application.create();

  App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("about", function(){
      this.route("team")
    });
    this.route("contact");

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>{{#linkTo "index"}}Home{{/linkTo}}</li>
      <li>{{#linkTo "about"}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
        <ul>
          <li>{{#linkTo "about.team"}Team{{/linkTo}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>{{#linkTo "contact"}Contact{{/linkTo}}</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  {{outlet}}
  </script>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h1>Welcome to Ember.js </h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
    <h1>About Page</h1>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about/team">
    <h2>here is our team!</h2>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contact">
    <h1>Please contact us!</h1>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT
Turns out that it's because I did not end my double curly brackets on my handlebars with my links to "team" and "contacts.

Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some closing parenthesis on the link-to's. Here it is with the fix

```
  <li>{{#linkTo "about.team"}}Team{{/linkTo}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>{{#linkTo "contact"}}Contact{{/linkTo}}</li>
```

Easy thing to miss! Highly suggest keeping your console up in your browser, it'll catch parse errors.

Comment: Yeah that it was! Now I feel stupid. Thanks for pointing that it for me though. I appreciate it.